# Why modifying a shared variable in one threads affects the other thread even without using volatile?

Tags: java, multithreading, unit-testing

Here I have three simple classes:

Class 1:

```
public class ThreadSyncMain {

public static int count = 0; // volatile is not use

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Thread thread1 = new Thread( new Thread1(),"Thread1" ); 
    Thread thread2 = new Thread( new Thread2(),"Thread2");

    thread1.start();
    thread2.start();

}

}
```

Class 2:

```
public class Thread1 implements Runnable{
public void run() {

    System.out.println("Thread1 Count :: "+ThreadSyncMain.count);
    ThreadSyncMain.count++;
}

}
```

Class 3:

```
public class Thread2 implements Runnable{
public void run() {

        System.out.println("Thread2 Count :: "+ThreadSyncMain.count);

}
}
```

The output is:

Thread1 Count :: 0
Thread2 Count :: 1

This means thread1 changed the value of count. So why change in thread1 affects in thread2 as I am not using any "volatile" keyword. Is "volatile" keyword not a matter in this scenario? How can I modify the code so as to test "volatile"?

Thanks in advance.

Update part:
I am updating the code after doing some hit and trial testing. Class 1 remains same. Here is the updated code:

Class 2: I added 100 millisecond delay.

```
public class Thread1 implements Runnable{
public void run() {

    System.out.println("Thread1 Count :: "+ThreadSyncMain.count);

    try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ThreadSyncMain.count++;
}

}
```

Class 3: Added while loop. Inside it count is continuously monitored.

```
public class Thread2 implements Runnable{
public void run() {

    while(true)
    {
        if(ThreadSyncMain.count == 1)
        { 
            System.out.println("Thread2 Count :: "+ThreadSyncMain.count);
        }
    }

}
}
```

Now in this situation I have got the following outputs:
1. If "volatile" is not used in class1 output is:

```
 Thread1 Count :: 0
```

2. If "volatile" is used in class1 output is:

```
Thread1 Count :: 0
Thread2 Count :: 1
Thread2 Count :: 1
Thread2 Count :: 1
.
.
.
```

Why volatile comes into picture in this scenario?

Answer (score 3):

There's a memory view associated with each thread. These views are not guaranteed to be consistent between threads without the usage of locks. As such, sharing a variable as you've done above (without `volatile`) will work, since it's visible across threads, but can give you unreliable results. Using the `volatile` keyword means that the variable is *consistently* read between threads.

See [here](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html#volatile), and in particular note:

> Volatile fields are special fields which are used for communicating
>   state between threads. Each read of a volatile will see the last write
>   to that volatile by any thread; in effect, they are designated by the
>   programmer as fields for which it is never acceptable to see a "stale"
>   value as a result of caching or reordering.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have updated the post. So can you please give the reason for the updated part. It is because I am trying to differentiate correct scenarios for using and not using "volatile".:)

Answer (score 3):

`Volatile` will *guarantee* the side effects from thread 1 become visible to thread 2. Without `volatile`, changes might, or might not, be visible.

Testing the effect of `volatile` is difficult, since it depends on low level aspects like hardware architecture, threading implementation, compiler optimization, and exact timing of even by the scheduler.

If I were to do so, I would write multithreaded tests that generate a high concurrency, and make sure I run on a multi-processor implementation. Then I might observe differences between code with and without `volatile`. The outcome of the tests would still be undeterministic.

Comment: I think your last sentence is key here

Answer (score 1):

It is possible the compiler isn't caching counter because it is a class wide variable. So the writes are in memory.

If you want to test volatile and non volatile write/reads..

```
public class VolatileExperiment
{
  private int counter ;
  private volatile int volatile_counter;
  public void Counter()
  {
     new Thread( new Runnable(){
     public void run()
     {
        ++counter;
        ++volatile_counter;
        //print
      }
    }).start();


   new Thread( new Runnable(){
     public void run()
     {
       ++counter;
       ++volatile_counter;
       //print
      }
    }).start();
    //print counter 
   //print volatile 
  }
```

}

Using volatile ensures that compiler doesn't optimize code, so writes are done in memory and not in thread memory. So you should see `volatile_counter` updated.. while `counter` may not be  affected