# Thread able to see the updated static variable set by the main thread in java

Tags: java, multithreading, static, volatile

can you please clarify me what is the problem with code:

Q: Even though i am not declaring the blinker as volatile, but thread t1 able to see the updated value(true) set by the main thread….

code:

```
package com.learning;
public class HowToStopRunningThread implements Runnable{
/**
* @param args
*/
public static boolean blinker;

public static void main(String[] args) {
Thread t = new Thread(new HowToStopRunningThread());
t.start();
HowToStopRunningThread obj = new HowToStopRunningThread();
obj.stop();
}

public void stop(){
try{
Thread.sleep(100);
System.out.println(“Setting the Blinker value”);
blinker = true;
}catch(InterruptedException ie){
ie.getMessage();
}
}


@Override
public void run() {
while(!blinker){
try{
System.out.println(“blinker:”+blinker);
Thread.sleep(1000);
}catch(InterruptedException ie){
ie.getMessage();
}
}
}
}
```

Output:

```
blinker:false
Setting the Blinker value
```

———————————
and then thread came out of the while loop

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why modifying a shared variable in one threads affects the other thread even without using volatile?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13376713/why-modifying-a-shared-variable-in-one-threads-affects-the-other-thread-even-wit)

Answer (score 6):

volatile *guarantees* that the new value will be visible by other threads. But that doesn't mean that changes to non-volatile variables are guaranteed to be invisible.

In short, this works by accident, and is not guaranteed to work always and everywhere.

In this case, it certainly works because both threads print to System.out, and println is a synchronized method. And synchronized also offers visibility guarantees.